# при переходе исчезает NavigationController

Tags: ios, swift

Я новичок, у меня есть `NavigationController` с `ViewController`, и view со своим контроллером `CurrencyViewController`, и в `DialogViewController`, в котором присутствует 4 DLRadioButton, при нажатии обрабатываю событие на переход в предыдущий view, использую код `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "close", sender: self)` (да, segue привязал) получаю переход но исчезает панель навигации, подскажите как с этим бороться ?
Что пробовал:

1. В жизненных циклах контроллера пробовал `navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden`
2. Использовал такое

> let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:
>   Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"close")

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал в таких функциях

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: Внутри какой функции вы используете setNavigationBarHidden? Можете привести больше кода?

Comment: выше добавил код, вызывал в CurrencyViewController и DialogViewController

Comment: Полный код вызова CurrencyViewController покажите тоже пожалуйста. И вообще - можете в идеале сделать example и выложить на GitHub? Т.к. причины могут быть разные.

Comment: https://github.com/lord-v/countermoney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут проблема скорее в архитектуре, а не в функциях.
После того, как вы отобразили окно выбора валюты, не надо использовать performSegue для нового вызова CurrencyViewController.

Вместо этого надо передать значение выбранной валюты через протокол,  Singleton или NotificationCenter, а окно выбора закрыть.

**Способ через протокол:**

Добавьте файл closeProtocol:

```
protocol closeProtocol {
    func closeModal()
    var selectedCurrency: String? { get set }
}
```

Укажите что CurrencyViewController должен реализовывать closeProtocol:

```
class CurrencyViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate, closeProtocol
```

В DialogViewController добавьте:

```
var delegate: closeProtocol?
```

В CurrencyViewController добавьте:

```
var popVC: DialogViewController?
var selectedCurrency: String?
```

И измените начало функции tapped() на:

```
self.popVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popVC") as! DialogViewController
popVC?.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
popVC?.delegate = self
```

Добавьте функцию closeModal() в CurrencyViewController:

```
func closeModal() {
    labelcurrencyDestination = self.selectedCurrency ?? "Гривна"
    currency.text = labelcurrencyDestination
    popVC?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Функцию selectCurrency в DialogViewController измените на:

```
@IBAction func selectCurrency(_ sender: DLRadioButton) {
    delegate?.selectedCurrency = sender.titleLabel?.text
    delegate?.closeModal()
}
```

**Что получится в итоге:**
При выборе валюты вы через делегат передаете выбранную валюту в основной экран и в этот же экран передаете команду закрыть попап окно.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь и объяснение, все работает)